# I am trying to update mysql database, but I am getting an undefined offset notice error but database was updated. Kindly provide the solution for this

Tags: php

Updated! Updated!

> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\update1\update.php on line 8
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\update1\update.php on line 9
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\update1\update.php on line 10
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\update1\update.php on line 11
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\update1\update.php on line 12

Updated!

> Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\update1\update.php on line 8
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\update1\update.php on line 9
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\update1\update.php on line 10
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\update1\update.php on line 11
>   Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\update1\update.php on line 12

Updated!

```
$size  = array($_POST['NO_OF_CLASSES'],$_POST['NO_OF_CLASSES_PRESENT'],$_POST['NO_OF_CLASSES_ABSENT'],$_POST['PERCENTAGE']);    
$size1 = count($size);
for($i = 0; $i<$size1;$i++) 
{
    $regno = $_POST['REGNO'][$i];
    $Noofclasses= $_POST['NO_OF_CLASSES'][$i];
    $Noofclassespresent= $_POST['NO_OF_CLASSES_PRESENT'][$i];
    $Noofclassesabsent= $_POST['NO_OF_CLASSES_ABSENT'][$i];
    $percentage= $_POST['PERCENTAGE'][$i];
    $query = "UPDATE attendancetbl SET NO_OF_CLASSES='$Noofclasses',NO_OF_CLASSES_PRESENT='$Noofclassespresent',NO_OF_CLASSES_ABSENT='$Noofclassesabsent',PERCENTAGE='$percentage' WHERE REGNO =  '$regno'";
    mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");
    echo "<em>Updated!</em><br />";
}
```

Comment: Maybe look on lines 8, 9, 10, 11, and 12. The errors are telling you where to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the index of the array you are try to access is not set for example:

```
$_POST['REGNO'][3] and so on.
```

Please, `print_r` your $size array before the for loop and exit and and you will see what I am talking about

Answer (score 0):

number of records(rows) is minimum compared to the length of the array. So only offset error is occurred. Solution for this count the number of records and write a forloop to manipulate.